# Need help for an app to push a file with a button

Tags: android, root

Okay, Im very new to android programming, and im making a root app to push a specific file to /system/framework with a button

how can i accomplish this? i tried the command style and none are working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of steps you need to take to be able to do this.

First (of course) the device needs to be rooted.  You can check this in a number of ways.

The following code will check if the "su" command returns a command not found error (su binary exists) AND that a super user app is installed to grant the permissions after you request them.

```
 private boolean isDeviceRooted() {

            // check for SU command in shell
            if ((new ExecShell().executeCommand(ExecShell.SHELL_COMMAND.su_check) != null) && (appInstalled("eu.chainfire.supersu.nonag") || appInstalled("eu.chainfire.supersu") || appInstalled("com.noshufou.android.su") || appInstalled("com.koushikdutta.superuser"))) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Device Rooted");
                return true;
            }

            // check for SU application installed
            if (appInstalled("eu.chainfire.supersu.nonag") || appInstalled("eu.chainfire.supersu") || appInstalled("com.noshufou.android.su") || appInstalled("com.koushikdutta.superuser")) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Device Rooted");
                return true;
            }

            Log.i(TAG, "Device Not Rooted");
            return false;
        }


        private boolean appInstalled(String uri) {
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            boolean app_installed = false;
            try {
                pm.getPackageInfo(uri, PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
                app_installed = true;
            } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
                app_installed = false;
            }
            return app_installed;
        }
```

If this code returns false you could set a flag or display and error, else continue.

Then, once you know the device is rooted, you want to execute the necessary root commands to do what you need.

The following code takes as input String[] of commands, and executes them sequentially as root.

```
public boolean RunAsRoot(String[] cmds) {
    Process p;
    try {
        p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        try {
            for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd + "\n");
            }
            os.writeBytes("exit\n");
            os.flush();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

In your case you will first want to mount /system as rw.  There is lots of information on the web to help you find the command you want but it will look something like
`mount -o remount rw /system mount -o remount rw /system`

You then want to move the file you want using either `mv` or `cp`.

An example of the use of the root commands would be

```
String[] cmds = {"mount -o remount rw /system mount -o remount rw /system", "cp /sdcard/myfile /system/framework/myfile"};
if(!RunAsRoot(cmds)){
    //Commands failed to run, show an error/retry
}
```

This covers the "hard" bit which is the root functionality.

An easy tutorial for the button can be found [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/button/android-button-example/).

Program flow could be

```
onCreate(){
    checkIsRooted();
    Button x = (Button) findViewById(R.id.x);
    x.setOnClickListener(onClickListener());
}

onClickListener(){
    onClick(){
        String[] cmds = {...};
        if(!runAsRoot(cmds))
            AlertDialog.Builder.makeText(...).show();
    }
}
```

NOTE, THIS IS PSEUDO CODE, YOU CAN'T COPY AND PASTE THIS CODE TO MAKE IT WORK, YOU NEED TO DO IT PROPERLY YOURSELF!